# How to create a circular frequency histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

Dear members of stackoverflow,

I want to create a circular frequency histogram (rose diagram) using the the frequencies for each bin listed as a single column in a text file. How could I do this using matplotlib.pyplot and numpy in python3?

I did an initial attempt with a code I found on the internet, but when I get the rose diagram the bins are overlapped when they should be beside each other. Other detail: the radius of the circle for each bin should be the frequency, but this also changes and does not match my frequencies.
I want my bins to go from 0 to 360 degrees with width of 10 degrees; example: 0-10, 10-20 etc.

This is a sample of the txt file with the frequencies(frequencies.txt):

```
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
1
1
0
1
0
0
1
2
29
108
262
290
184
81
25
7
2
3
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a polar bar plot. The angles need to be converted from degrees to radians.

`frequencies = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')` would read the values from file ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequencies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 29, 108, 262, 290,
               184, 81, 25, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)

theta = np.radians(np.arange(0, 360, 10))
width = np.radians(10)
ax.bar(theta, frequencies, width=width,
       facecolor='lightblue', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.5, align='edge')
ax.set_xticks(theta)
plt.show()
```

[image: polar bar plot]

Comment: JohanC, thank you very much this code truly works.